# Decimal numbers in a HTML cfgridcolumn

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-9, cfgrid, cfgridcolumn

For some reason all my cfgrids drop the ending 0 of dollar amounts. So 104.50 is coming up as 104.5 and 332.80 is coming up as 332.8

It displays the last digit if it is not a 0. So 345.43 is fine.

I have tried using the currency type but that only works with flash grids.

This seems like an easy problem but I am stuck and everything I am trying is not working.

Any help on this would be great.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is for CF9 (ExtJS 3.x).

```
<cfsavecontent variable="formatGridInit">
<script language="javaScript">
formatgrid = function() {
    var myFormatter = Ext.util.Format.numberRenderer('.00');
    var mygrid = ColdFusion.Grid.getGridObject('testgrid');
    var cm = mygrid.getColumnModel();
    cm.setRenderer(2, myFormatter);
    mygrid.reconfigure(mygrid.getStore(),cm);
};
</script>
</cfsavecontent>
<cfhtmlhead text="#formatGridInit#">
<cfset ajaxOnLoad("formatgrid")>
```

Make sure your HTML has `<head></head>` in order for `<cfhtmlhead>` to work.

replace `testgrid` with your grid's name, and `2` on 2nd last line to the column index you want to apply the formatter to.