# cfgridcolumn mask to format numbers

Tags: extjs, coldfusion, cfgrid

According to the docs, I should be able to use the mask attribute to format my column:

```
<cfgridcolumn name="salary" type="numeric" mask="$999,999">
```

I have a salary amount I want to show as

```
$100,000
 $80,000
  $5,000
```

Any ideas why its not working?

Full code snipit for testing below.

```
<cfscript>
        rs = QueryNew('salary', 'integer');
        QueryAddRow(rs,3);
        QuerySetCell(rs, 'salary', '100000', 1);
        QuerySetCell(rs, 'salary', '80000', 2);
        QuerySetCell(rs, 'salary', '5000', 3);
</cfscript>

<cfform>
    <cfgrid format="html" name="demo" query="rs">
        <cfgridcolumn name="salary" type="numeric" mask="$999,999">
    </cfgrid>
</cfform>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I need to give props to @Henry for this answer that I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8098332/decimal-numbers-in-a-html-cfgridcolumn) and applied to your case.  I had not used this before but I tested it and it does work (using CF9).  See [this other](http://www.danvega.org/blog/2008/3/20/CFGrid-Event-Listeners) reference that I found as well.  Interesting stuff.  Anyway...

For your issue try this code:

```
<html>
    <head><title>Test</title></head>
<body>
<cfsavecontent variable="formatGridInit">
<script language="javaScript">
formatgrid = function() {
    var myFormatter = Ext.util.Format.numberRenderer('$000,000');
    var mygrid = ColdFusion.Grid.getGridObject('demo');
    var cm = mygrid.getColumnModel();
    cm.setRenderer(0, myFormatter);
    mygrid.reconfigure(mygrid.getStore(),cm);
};
</script>
</cfsavecontent>
<cfhtmlhead text="#formatGridInit#">
<cfset ajaxOnLoad("formatgrid")>

<cfscript>
        rs = QueryNew('salary', 'integer');
        QueryAddRow(rs,3);
        QuerySetCell(rs, 'salary', '100000', 1);
        QuerySetCell(rs, 'salary', '80000', 2);
        QuerySetCell(rs, 'salary', '5000', 3);
</cfscript>

<cfform>
    <cfgrid format="html" name="demo" query="rs">
        <cfgridcolumn name="salary" type="numeric">
    </cfgrid>
</cfform>
</body>
</html>
```

**NOTE** - Make sure your HTML has `<head></head>` in order for the `<cfhtmlhead>` to work.

**NOTE** - The grid name in this code `var mygrid = ColdFusion.Grid.getGridObject('demo');` must match your grid's name.

**NOTE** - Set the number in this code `cm.setRenderer(0, myFormatter);` to the column that you want to apply the format to (columns in the grid are zero based).

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the "currency" type which would support the mask you used is only available in format="flash|applet" mode only.

The easiest way would be format the data in the query before it hits the CFGRID. Alternatively you could just reformat those cells using ColdFusion:

```
<cfscript>
        rs = QueryNew('salary', 'varchar');
        QueryAddRow(rs,3);
        QuerySetCell(rs, 'salary', '100000', 1);
        QuerySetCell(rs, 'salary', '80000', 2);
        QuerySetCell(rs, 'salary', '5000', 3);
</cfscript>

<!--- Loop Over Query and Reformat Salary --->
<cfloop query="rs" startrow="1">
    <cfscript>
        QuerySetCell(rs, 'salary', dollarFormat(salary), currentrow);
    </cfscript>
</cfloop>

<cfform>
    <cfgrid format="html" name="demo" query="rs">
        <cfgridcolumn name="salary">
    </cfgrid>
</cfform>
```

Comment: That wont work, it will break the sorting as it will be returned as a string. It needs to be done grid side.

Comment: And SQL Formatting is not an option? Or you need sorting in the grid?

Comment: SQL Formatting will also break sorting